# Azure Functions don't publish appsettings.prod.json file

Tags: c#, .net, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I'm deploying my .NET Core Console app to Azure Function, and for this reason I'm using appsettings.json files because we don't have time to change it to local.settings.json file right now.

After publishing the app in Azure Function through VSCode, appsettings.json and appsettings.dev.json exists in the `/azure-functions-host/` directory, but not the appsettings.prod.json.

I have these copy properties in a dependent project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\..\appsettings.prod.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="..\..\appsettings.dev.json" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="..\..\appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Exception:

```
The configuration file 'appsettings.prod.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is '/azure-functions-host/appsettings.prod.json'.\n   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at DataImoveis.Setup.SetupConfig.LoadConfig(IServiceCollection service) in /mnt/d/Cloud/dev/src/DataImoveis.Setup/SetupConfig.cs:line 26
```

My LoadConfig function:

```
        public static void LoadConfig(IServiceCollection service)
        {
            string env = "dev";

            if (!checkFunctionEnvironment(ref env))
            {
                checkIfRelease(ref env);
            }

            var currentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(currentPath)
                .AddJsonFile(
                    "appsettings.json",
                    optional: false,
                    reloadOnChange: true
                )
                .AddJsonFile(
                    $"appsettings.{env}.json",
                    optional: false,
                    reloadOnChange: true
                );
            service
                .AddDefaultAWSOptions(config.Build().GetAWSOptions())
                .Configure<Settings>(config.Build());
        }
```

What this happens? Why just this file isn't published?
I've tried a lot of things like `CopyToPublishDirectory = Always` option and other stuff.

I've searched for the appsettings.prod.json file inside of the image/host and I haven't found it.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right entry point? Maybe try `builder.GetContext().ApplicationRootPath` instead of `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`.

Comment: Yes. This path points to the /azure-functions-host directory where are those files published for the app, and where are the appsettings.dev.json and appsettings.json files.

Comment: are you using VS2019?

Comment: I'm using VSCode

Comment: Can you try changing it to <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Comment: @JasonPan I haven't accepted your post as answer because I followed your steps and even though isn't working for me.

Comment: You also can use FTP to access the path.

Comment: My description or code is very clear. If you really think it is not helpful, you should not find the answer you want in the SO forum.

Comment: It was solved when I've changed the application context at the DependencyInjection config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Use `ResolvedFileToPublish` in `ItemGroup` can solve your issues.**

Below is my test steps.

**Step 1.**

I create `appsettings.dev.json` and `appsettings.prod.json` in my local like below.

[image]

**Step 2.**

Add below settings in your  `<projectname>.csproj` file.

[image]

*Sample code.*

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="azure-functions-host/appsettings.prod.json">
    <RelativePath>azure-functions-host/appsettings.prod.json</RelativePath>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="azure-functions-host/appsettings.dev.json">
    <RelativePath>azure-functions-host/appsettings.dev.json</RelativePath>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
</ItemGroup>
```

**Step 3.**

Check files in scm site.

[image]

**Step 4.**

Check my test function url.

[image]

*My test code.*

```
    [FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        bool isLocal = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID"));
        var jsonString=string.Empty;
        if(isLocal){
            jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(@"C:\home\site\wwwroot\azure-functions-host","appsettings.dev.json"));
        }else{
            try
            {
                jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(@"C:\home\site\wwwroot\azure-functions-host","appsettings.prod.json"));
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                jsonString=e.ToString();
                throw;
            }
            
        }
        
        string response = isLocal ? "Function is running on local environment." : "Function is running on Azure.";

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        return new OkObjectResult(jsonString);
    }
```

Comment: How can I use SCM or File explorer using Azure Functions? I'm using the Pay-As-You-Go subscription.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito Same as azure web app.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito Before azurewebsites in url, add scm like my gif in answer.

Comment: Thank you. It's woking putting the scm in the middle of the URL, but I don't have many options inside the Azure App Service, just two links to "App Settings" or "Deployments" and another Wiki Link.

Comment: I'm starting to believe that this problem or maybe the limited kudu it's related with my account (it's an DEV profile account) or my function on linux.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito Maybe, but you can get the running path of the current project through the code, and then create the corresponding folder locally to store the files you want, and then modify the csproj file according to my suggestions, which can achieve the same effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231569/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-mayconfsbrito).

Comment: @mayconfsbrito If there is a problem with the product, raise a suuport ticket on portal. From a technical level, I can only provide a method to verify it, and the solution is definitely correct. If you want, I hope you can accept my answer, so that you can help more forum users.