# Visual Studio copies .dll's to Bin folder on Publish

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, dll, azure-functions

**I have the following issue.**

I've created an **Azure function** and want to run a compiler stored in `{ProjectFile}/AlCompiler` folder.

The folder contains **.dll's** and **alc.exe** file. The exe-file requires these **.dll's** to run, otherwise produces an error.

I tried to publish the files of **AlCompiler** folder to **wwwroot** directory *adding following to the .csproj project file:*

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="AlCompiler/**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

*Also I tried this markup:*

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="AlCompiler/**">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <TargetPath>AlCompiler\%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
```

And tried to use `<Link>` attribute:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="AlCompiler/**">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <Link>AlCompiler\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

**All of these causes the files of AlCompiler directory being split up on publish:**

- **exe and some other files go to wwwroot/AlCompiler folder**
- **all the .dll's go to wwwroot/bin/AlCompiler folder**

I didn't find any way to keep them in one place.

**So I cannot run alc.exe file due to .dll's being missing.**

I'd be very glad for your help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've came across the solution, just doing things vice versa.

Instead of trying to add .**dll's** to Compiler folder (where .**exe** is stored), I add .**exe's** to bin folder (where .**dll's** are stored).

Don't know if it's the best solution but it works:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="AlCompiler/**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      <TargetPath>bin\AlCompiler\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code in your `.csproj`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="your_folder/yourfile">
    <RelativePath>your_folder/yourfile</RelativePath>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="azure-functions-host/appsettings.prod.json">
    <RelativePath>azure-functions-host/appsettings.prod.json</RelativePath>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="azure-functions-host/appsettings.dev.json">
    <RelativePath>azure-functions-host/appsettings.dev.json</RelativePath>
    </ResolvedFileToPublish>
</ItemGroup>
```

**For more details, you can see my answer in below post.**

[1. Azure Functions don't publish appsettings.prod.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67181866/azure-functions-dont-publish-appsettings-prod-json-file/67206074#67206074)

[2. Unable to find files located in my root project folder when hosted on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279143/unable-to-find-files-located-in-my-root-project-folder-when-hosted-on-azure/62295252#62295252)

Comment: Thanks for a reply. For now I came out with my own solution that works. Will try to check out yours.

Comment: @AndriiDiachenko Okay, I'm glad you solved the problem. My method can also be solved. If you are interested, you can try it.

Comment: your method doesn't work for dlls - they are still copied to the bin/your_folder/yourfile folder instead of your_folder/yourfile. For other extensions it seems to work (I tried for .json and .exe files). Is there some additional xml attribute/property to override this behavior for dlls?